# Mac os Big Sur | No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, maven

I am getting this error on the screenshot and I have seen other posts about it, however, the fixes provided are mainly for Windows, so whatever I tried did not fix the issue on my Mac.

Currently, when I run /usr/libexec/java_home it points me here:
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

So when running a maven project it throughs message like this:
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

So, I am wondering if the location of JAVA_HOME is incorrect, and if so how can I fix it?
Sorry, if asking something obvious questions, but I am new to this.

I would really appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-2FE451B0-9572-4E38-A1A5-568B77B146DE)? In general, how did you install a JDK on your machine?

Comment: Yes. Installed successfully

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833334/build-failure-run-mvn-clean-install-i-just-upgraded-big-sur

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot

Answer (score 34):

I meet the same question as yours.
This solution ([Build failure run "mvn clean install". I just upgraded Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833334/build-failure-run-mvn-clean-install-i-just-upgraded-big-sur)) is to remove useless jre.
Mine is to give mvn shell a correct java_home.

### Solution - edit mvn bash

#### Step 1: Check how to filter your target java by `/usr/libexec/java_home`

When I run command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

I can see 2 virtual machines

```
MacBook-Pro:bin charles$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.251.08 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_251 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

My default return value of `/usr/libexec/java_home` is my jre path such as
**/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home**

But I can change the return jdk path
**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home**

if I run command
`/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0`

#### Step 2: Update mvn shell

Find following lines in mvn shell

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] && [ -x "/usr/libexec/java_home" ]; then
    #
    # Apple JDKs
    #
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
fi
```

Because I can use `usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0` to make sure system using jdk,
I update my shell as

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] && [ -x "/usr/libexec/java_home" ]; then
    #
    # Apple JDKs
    #
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0`
fi
```

And then, it works.

### How to check difference

`mvn -version`

Before I update my mvn, I will see

```
MacBook-Pro:~ charles$ mvn -version
Apache Maven ........
Maven home: ........
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
Default locale: zh_TW, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

After I update my mvn, I can see the result

```
MacBook-Pro:~ charles$ mvn -version
Apache Maven ........
Maven home: .......
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: zh_TW, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Though java home display as jre path, but the jre is sub-folder inside of jdk. It's ok.

Comment: This answer works for me on macOS.

Comment: how do you update your maven shell?

Comment: there's .mvnw file in your project, I guess the author is referring to that.

I would suggest to follow the link attached below as an extension to this answer 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72516836/8871869

Answer (score 5):

The default JRE comes with Mac is /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

I have installed JDK using a dmg file. Even after passing the JAVA_HOME to the new path from bashrc (`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home`), it was not taking.

To list the avaiable java installations

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.311.11 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_202 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In order to point to your JDK, just do the below.

```
% cd /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins
% ls
JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
$ sudo mv JavaAppletPlugin.plugin JavaAppletPlugin.plugin-backup
```

After that, if you run the command

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools from /usr/bin. This directory is part of the system software and any changes will be reset by Apple the next time that you perform an update of the OS.

Comment: Also make sure to change the java version inside Eclipse. Right click your Project Root >  Java build Path(left Pane) > Libraries [Tab] > Select JRE System (if present) , click Edit > Alternate JRE Radio > Installed JREs.. btn> go to the path of new JDK , till Home Directory > Name your new jdk1.8 so you can identify it from list of options > Finish >  Then make sure to select the new added jdk in Alternate JRE. 
After this additional step only it worked for me
Thanks for the solution before this!!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, and could not fix it using the answers provided, maven kept using the default jre and I was always getting the "No compiler error..". I managed to solve it setting the JAVA_HOME environment, so in my case I used the command:

> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_331.jdk/Contents/Home

After this command, the command mvn -v now outputs:

> Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec
> Java version: 1.8.0_331, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_331.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

Although it says /jre, the command that was failing, "mvn clean package -D skipTests", now executes properly.

So hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command to list the available java installations:

**$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V**

> Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
>
> 1.8.251.08 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
> 1.8.0_251 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8"  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home

Check the default return value of the following command which is jre path in my case:

**$/usr/libexec/java_home**

> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

Run the command to get JDK path:

**$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0**

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home

Add the following line in **.bash_profile** file:

**export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8.0)**

Comment: Also make sure to change the java version inside Eclipse. Right click your Project Root >  Java build Path(left Pane) > Libraries [Tab] > Select JRE System (if present) , click Edit > Alternate JRE Radio > Installed JREs.. btn> go to the path of new JDK , till Home Directory > Name your new jdk1.8 so you can identify it from list of options > Finish >  Then make sure to select the new added jdk in Alternate JRE. 
After this additional step only it worked for me
Thanks for the solution before this!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your terminal and edit the zshrc File with your own JAVA_HOME version

For step 3 enter your java version

Type:

1. vim ~/.zshrc
2. press i to insert and add your path to JAVA_HOME
3. export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home (OR WHATEVER YOUR JAVA PATH IS)
4. press control + c to exit insert mode on vim
5. Type :wq and it will save the document and quit vim editor
6. source ~/.zshrc
7. mvn -version

After you type mvn -version after all these steps You will be able to see your JAVA version and vendor update from the default
"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home" to the java version you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I edit for MacOS ventura , Eclipse/STS and it worked.I use Spring Tool Suite.

Go to Eclipse/STS -->Preferences/Settings --> Java -->Installed JRE's

If you see this as the first path among installed JRE's remove it.This does not include jdk.

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home.

Eclipse will automatically take the next installed JDK library  which is the jdk 1.8.0_361. Pls make sure you have added a jdk library of your choice in the first place into installed jre's.

As a pre-requisite to this, make sure that your JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME are all set correctly and that mvn -version returns the right jdk version before modifying anything in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

When you checked

```
mvn -version
```

You will get the below message (Which the Java runtime is pointing to /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home):

```
Apache Maven 3.9.1 
Maven home: /Applications/Naveen Gowda/Own Project/apache-maven-3.9.1
Java version: 1.8.0_361, runtime: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.2.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

1. Give below command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

You will get this:-

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.361.09 (x86_64)  - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_202 (x86_64)  - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

2. Then change path to JDK path and execute this command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

3. Now check the Maven version again:

```
mvn -version
```

Now you will get below which is pointing to JDK path:

```
Apache Maven 3.9.1 
Maven home: /Applications/Naveen Gowda/Own Project/apache-maven-3.9.1
Java version: 1.8.0_202, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Also make sure to change the java version inside Eclipse. Right click your Project Root >  Java build Path(left Pane) > Libraries [Tab] > Select JRE System (if present) , click Edit > Alternate JRE Radio > Installed JREs.. btn> go to the path of new JDK , till Home Directory > Name your new jdk1.8 so you can identify it from list of options > Finish >  Then make sure to select the new added jdk in Alternate JRE. 
After this additional step only it worked for me
Thanks for the solution before this!!