# MacOS No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, macos, maven, configuration

I can compiling the project from intellij but I can not compile from terminal(iTerm)

I am getting this error:

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

---

**mvn -v:**

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2

Maven home: /Users/myusername/developer_tools/apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_202, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

---

echo $JAVA_HOME:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

**java -version:**

```
java version "1.8.0_202"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
```

---

this is my .zshrc file and maven and java paths

**open -e .zshrc**

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/myusername/developer_tools/apache-maven-3.5.2
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

When I run mvn -v java home path is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre` is it related with this? why does jre appear here?

Comment: Maybe [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66479986/5489512) will help.

Comment: ı tried this solution but I am still getting error